# How do operating systems deal with fork bombs?

Tags: operating-system

Consider the following fork bomb in Python ([source](https://github.com/aaronryank/fork-bomb/blob/master/fork-bomb.py)):

```
import os
while 1:
    os.fork()
```

I'm too afraid to test it out myself, but I'm somewhat skeptical that if I just took this program and ran it my computer would just freeze up and die. Assuming this is true, my question is -- what mechanisms or policies is my operating system using to fight it off?

My question can be viewed as sort of an "application" problem to what one might learn in an OS class.

Comment: There's only one way to know ;)

Comment: Probably OOM killer will be called at some point.

Comment: @wxz Google helped me out a bit with that, but I think it would make a good answer if you could expound on what the OOM killer does/how it works/etc. :)

Comment: see also: https://superuser.com/questions/435690/does-linux-have-any-measures-to-protect-against-fork-bombs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected, when I tried it out on my machine, the computer froze and I had to hard reboot. So definitely don't do this on a regular basis.

The last error that I was able to capture from the program was:

```
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
     File "fork_bomb.py", line 3, in <module>
       os.fork()
```

So at some point, the OS couldn't handle the OS fork calls and returned an error. The only other useful message I can see from `/var/log/syslog` is

```
cgroup: fork rejected by pids controller in /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-2.scope
```

Cgroups are a way to restrict resources from processes within a particular cgroup. So presumably, the python processes were in a cgroup that had reached its pid/task limit. So that's one way the OS tries to deal with fork bombs, is limiting tasks using cgroups. Of course, the infinite loop of forks, even if the forks were failing, still required overhead from requesting resources from the OS, hence the system freeze.

Theoretically, another way the OS can try to limit fork bombs is through memory limits. Ignoring copy-on-write, if all the forked processes required extra memory, the Linux OOM (out of memory) killer will be called. This kernel process will be awakened when memory is tight and then its job is to start killing processes that it thinks will help free up sufficient memory to keep the system running. Memory limits can be set using cgroups or by setting the minimum free memory using `/proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes`.